# Adicionar um novo valor no início de uma serie pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Como faço para adicionar um novo valor a uma serie pandas?

Realizei a cópia da serie do dataframe e agora preciso adicionar um novo valor a série  `swap_hoje`, porém, ao invés de ser no final da série, preciso que seja no início, na `index 0`.

```
swap_hoje = swap_dataframe['Valor'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Preciso também, adicionar um valor na série `swap_ontem`:

```
swap_ontem = swap_dataframe['Valor'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Porém, neste último, terá de ser no final da série.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Editada (Inserção no meio da serie):**
>  
>   Fiz uma iserção no meio da serie, [veja no codigo.](https://repl.it/IwBS/3)

Tente o codigo abaixo, [veja-o rodando aqui](https://repl.it/IwBS/3).

```
import pandas as pd
serie = pd.Series()

for n in range(5):
    serie = serie.set_value(n, n*n)

# Antes da inserção
print (serie)
```

**Output:**

```
0     0
1     1
2     4
3     9
4    16
dtype: int64
```

**Inserção e append:**

```
# Convert a serie em uma lista
lst = serie.tolist()

# faz a inserção na lista
lst.insert(0,999)

# Inserindo na posição 3
lst.insert(3,'Inserção na posição 3')

# Faz append na lista
lst.append(1000)

# Converte a lista para serie
serie = pd.Series(lst)

# Pos inserção/append
print(serie)
```

**Output:**

```
0                      999
1                        0
2                        1
3    Inserção na posição 3
4                        4
5                        9
6                       16
7                     1000
dtype: object
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/IwBS/3)

Comment: Na verdade, o que o seu código faz é substituir o valor da posição 0, certo? Acredito que não me expressei de forma clara! Preciso que um novo valor seja inserido na posição 0, e que o antigo valor da posição 0, vá para a posição 1 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: É como se você desse um append, só que ao invés de o valor novo entrar no final da serie, ele entra no início!

Comment: Entendi, na verdade eu é que não prestei a atenção devida, perae... la vai uma nova versãoi.

Comment: Veja se a nova versão atende.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a série criada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214408/49033):

```
import pandas as pd
serie = pd.Series()
for n in range(5):
    serie = serie.set_value(n, n*n)

serie
0     0
1     1
2     4
3     9
4    16
dtype: int64

serie2 = pd.Series(100)
serie2
0    100
dtype: int64

serie.append(serie2, ignore_index=True)
0      0
1      1
2      4
3      9
4     16
5    100
dtype: int64

serie2.append(serie, ignore_index=True)
0    100
1      0
2      1
3      4
4      9
5     16
dtype: int64
```